# Elasticsearch, Mapping, Date Mapping Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm having a weird experience with Elasticsearch with Date field type. I've tried about 7-10 different types of format, singular and multiple, and looked at and followed verbatim the Elasticsearch docs from current version on it, and I'm still getting the same error. Here is the current snippet:

```
"<REDACTED>": {"type": "date", "format": "date_optional_time||strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa||MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"}
```

The fourth format of: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss , matches my current data format, per the error message I repeatedly get:

error: elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [] of type [date] in document with id ' ...Preview of Field's Value: '2021-03-27 22:46:08'")

Can anyone provide any advice? It would be most appreciated ^___^

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch date formats adhere to the [`DateTimeFormatter` spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) which doesn't support `aa` — only a single `a` to denote am/pm.

Remove the double `a`s from the mapping:

```json
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "your_date_field": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_optional_time||strict_date_optional_time||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a||MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And indexing should work just fine:

```json
POST my-index/_doc
{
  "your_date_field": "2021-03-27 22:46:08"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The python code was looping over the previous as  a check, instead of replacing the index entirely with the new date stamp formats. once I erased the erroneous index by DELETE of the old index, code worked as intended.

Joe Sorocin was right as well regarding the aa. Joda format supports it, but only as a single a, two "a" is not required or correct.